# I am getting a Name error during an If statement

Tags: python, nameerror

I am getting a name error not defined error when entering bond into the program.

If anyone could shed some light onto where I have gone wrong that would be great.

```
elif  greeting == "Bond":
      house_value = int (input('''Please enter the value of the house:   '''))
      monthly_rate=float(input('''Enter the percentage of your interest rate ''')) / 100 /12 
      monthly_repay=int(input('''Please enter the number of months you plan to take to repay the bond'''))
      x = (monthly_rate * house_value)/(1 - (1+monthly_rate)**(-monthly_repay))
      print(f"The monthly repayment is {x:.2f}")      


if     y == 'Simple':
       compound = investment* math.pow((1+rate),years)
       print(f"The total amount of interest you will earn on your investment will be {compound:.2f} ")
```

Answer (score 5):

If you enter `elif  greeting == "Bond":` then `y` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested if-statements, watch the indentation, for example, by moving the last if-elif statement under if greeting.

```py
if greeting == investment:

...

   if y == simple:

    ...

       elif y == compound:

       ...

       elif greeting == bond:

...
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken